# script is not working on click,its working on hover only..??c

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am using one script that is working on mouse hover,bt not working 
    on click,can tell me..here is the script nd the website link..even
     i have changed thathover to click  then also its not working...

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/29/awesome-bubble-navigation-with-jquery/

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#nav > div').hover(
            function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.find('img').stop().animate({
                    'width': '310px',
                    'height': '110px',
                    'top': '45px',
                    'left': '35px',
                    'opacity': '1.0'
                }, 500, 'easeOutBack', function () {
                    $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeIn(700);
                });

                $this.find('a:first,h2').addClass('active');
            },
            function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.find('ul').fadeOut(500);
                $this.find('img').stop().animate({
                    'width': '52px',
                    'height': '52px',
                    'top': '0px',
                    'left': '0px',
                    'opacity': '0.1'
                }, 5000, 'easeOutBack');

                $this.find('a:first,h2').removeClass('active');
            }
        );
    });


   http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/29/awesome-bubble-navigation-with-jquery/
```

Comment: you cannot pass two functions inside the click event like hover. For a click effect in the same case use toggle instead of "hover"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(/*selector*/).hover(/*smth*/).on('click', function() { /*your click function*/ });
```